# Issue with Perl File::stat output, need to show date

Tags: perl

I am having an issue with getting File::stat to output the last modified date of the file. This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::localtime;
use File::stat;
use warnings;
use File::Find;



my $dirloc = 'E:\tmp\testdir';

sub find_txt {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;
    if ( ! -d $F && $F =~ /.tar|.exe|.zip/ ) {  
        my @result = $F;

        foreach my $result (@result){
            my $timestamp;
            $timestamp = (stat("$result"))->[9] or die "No $_: $!";
            print "$result : $timestamp\n";

        }
    }
}


find({wanted => \&find_txt}, $dirloc);
```

It is outputing something like this:

C:/tmp/testdir/foo/bar/test.tar : 1415305933

I need it to output instead (date format doesn't have to be what is listed, i just want to see the date):

C:/tmp/testdir/foo/bar/test.tar : 11/07/2014

I know that the output it is giving me is the time since epoch but I thought stat was supposed to give the date. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

edit: I have tried localtime, and i get: Time::tm=ARRAY(0x245b220), not sure what is happening there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `localtime` (Note: not `Time::localtime`) function to convert the timestamp into something useful

```
my $date = localtime $timestamp
```

which will make it a human readable string like `Fri Nov 7 15:33:00 2014`

Or you can use it in a list context to spit it into individual fields:

```
my($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $month, $year, $weekday, $yearOfDay, $isDST) = localtime $timestamp
```

Comment: If I use localtime I get: Time::tm=ARRAY(0x245b220), I have tried local time in the past and wasn't sure why that was happening

Comment: @EvanMiller remove `use Time::localtime;`  the localtime function I use in my answer is a built in Perl function not from the Time module